# ms office word 2003 and word 2007 styles

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, formatting

I have a paper written on Microsoft Word 2003 with a lot of styles. I wish to do another paper, but to use those styles. How can I do that?

I have Microsoft Word 2003 and Word 2007 on my machine.

many thanks

Comment: Does it keep the styles if you copy the file and delete the content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save styles as a quick style set

- open document with styles you want to use
- Home tab, Styles -> Change Styles -> Style Set -> Save as quick style set
- open new document
- Home tab, Styles -> Change Styles -> Style Set -> select the style set you just saved

Answer (score 3):

1)On the Tools menu, click Templates and Add-Ins.
2)Click Organizer, and then click the Styles tab.
 
3)To copy items to or from a different template (template: A file or files that contain the structure and tools for shaping such elements as the style and page layout of finished files. For example, Word templates can shape a single document, and FrontPage templates can shape an entire Web site.) or file, click Close File to close the active document (active document: The document in which you're working. Text you type or graphics you insert in Microsoft Word appear in the active document. The title bar of the active document is highlighted.) and its attached template or to close the Normal template (Normal template: A global template that you can use for any type of document. You can modify this template to change the default document formatting or content.). Then click Open File, and open the template or file you want.
 
4)Click the items you want to copy in either list, and then click Copy.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85935/how-do-i-export-styles-from-a-microsoft-word-2003-dot-file)

There is a 'Style Organizer' tool within Word which will let you copy styles from one document to another if they are both open at once.

In Word 2007:

```
* Open the styles dialog (Home tab -> Styles -> Bottom Right button).
* Click the 'manage styles' button.
* Click 'Import/Export...'
```